# angular 4 : Cannot read property of class variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning new to create app in angular 4 , Now in one of my file

```
export class AppComponent {
  str: string = "";
  arr = [];
  constructor(private elemRef: ElementRef, private rend: Renderer, private objComp: AppObjComponent) {

  }
  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) textKeyPressed(ev) {
      console.log(this.elemRef);
      if (ev) {
        this.str = ev.target.value;
        console.log(this.str);
        this.objComp.obj.forEach(function(elem, index) {

          if (elem.includes(this.str)) {
            this.arr.push(this.str);
          }

        })
      }
```

While compiling it compiles fine on the browser it throws error

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'str' of undefined
```

Which is this line

```
if(elem.includes(this.str))
```

But if i print it using console.log it prints in the same function .

```
console.log(this.str);
```

I am not sure why it throws error for this.str it also throws error for this.arr if I comment this.str line. Not sure why it is not able to access the class variables .

Comment: Try with:
`let that = this;
this.objComp.obj.forEach(function(elem, index) {
          if (elem.includes(that.str)) {
          }
        })`
and let me know

Comment: Although your answer is tecnically correct, in  modern js thats not a good practice for this case, better to use an arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this`in your forEach is not the `this` of your class.
To retain the context of your class, either use a fat-arrow :

```
this.objComp.obj.forEach((elem, index) => {
    if (elem.includes(this.str)) {
       this.arr.push(this.str);
    }
})
```

or use The `thisArg`parameter of forEach (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) that tells :

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be used as
>   callback's this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as
>   its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is
>   determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen
>   by a function.

So :

```
this.objComp.obj.forEach(function(elem, index) {
    if (elem.includes(this.str)) {
       this.arr.push(this.str);
    }
}, this ) // this added here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an arrow function in the for each or bind the scope to the function (preferably the first option)